# Unable to compile Android app with Sherloc theme

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Sorry to trouble i have been trying to fix these issues for the past 2 weeks anything you want to see i can post please help me solve this

I am using Eclipse not android studio here with also my style.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.App">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="title_text_style" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="title_bg">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_green</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="editext_register_style" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_bar_bg_register_big</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="tv_chat_menu_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_green</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.App.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.App.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

And this below is the errors i am getting when building

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v11    line 7  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'displayOptions'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v14    line 12 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.  styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values    line 48 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v14    line 10 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.  styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v11    line 5  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values    line 52 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'displayOptions'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values    line 53 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values    line 49 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v14    line 7  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'displayOptions'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v11    line 12 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.  styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v14    line 5  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar'. styles.xml  /Shooteka/res/values-v11    line 10 Android AAPT Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different case: '/Shooteka/bin/classes/com/chat'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent   Shooteka        Unknown Java Problem
```